How to align a VStack with 80% width with Texts centrally when it is in a ZStack?
I want to place a VStack including a few Text-Views in the center of the screen with a white background and opacity 50%. Therefore I tried the GeometryReader and know that it tries to consume 100% of the available size, but the end result looks strange. When I try to inspect the elements it seems to be caused by the ZStack containing the background image.
What do I need to do to align the VStack in the center?
ZStack {
            Image("demo-bg")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                VStack {

                    Text("Test1")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    Text("Test2")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    Text("Test3")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                    Text("Test4")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    TextField("Result", text: $result).keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
                .background(.white)
            }
        }

/

What iOS versions are you using? I'd recommend using containerRelativeFrame if you can.

I would suggest showing the Image using a .background modifier, so that the size of the image doesn't affect the layout. Then:

The ZStack is not needed any more, you can apply the image as background to the GeometryReader instead.
As you mentioned, a GeometryReader grabs all the available space. Unlike HStack, VStack and ZStack, which use center-alignment by default, the content of a GeometryReader is positioned with top-leading alignment. So after you have sized the main content to the size you want it to have and applied a background color (white), increase its size using maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity. This way, it fills the space of the GeometryReader.
The .frame modifier uses center alignment by default. If in fact you want some other kind of alignment, add an alignment parameter too.
Also, .edgesIgnoringSafeArea is deprecated, suggest using .ignoresSafeArea instead.

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            // ...
        }
        .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.8)
        .background(.white)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .background {
        Image("demo-bg")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


